# How to save HTML dynamic table into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

My problem is I am creating dynamic `HTML` table by using `javascript`.

How do I save this dynamic `HTML` table into a DataBase using CodeIginter?

This my input text code:

```
<table  id="tb3" name="tb3">
    <tr>
        <td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>        
        <td>
            <input  type="text" onkeyup="autofill()" id="Product_Code" name="Prdtcode" class="form-control input-xs Product_Code "     required>
        </td>

        <td ><input type="text" id="Product_Name" name="Prdtname" class="form-control input-xs"></td>

        <td><input  type="text" 
            onkeypress="javascript:doit_onkeypress(event)"  id="Qty" onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'addMore3')" name="Qty"class="form-control input-xs"    required>
        </td>

        <td><input  type="text" id="Rate"  class="form-control input-xs"name="Rate" value="" ></td>

        <td><input type="text" id="Value" name="Value" class="form-control input-xs"  ></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

This code gets data from a `TextBox` and displays in table format using `javascript`:

```
<table  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2" name="tb2">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
```

This is the `javascript` code to create table

```
function doit_onkeypress(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
        if(!checkEmptyInput()){
            var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
            cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
            cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
            cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
            cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
            cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4),
            code = document.getElementById("Product_Code").value,
            name = document.getElementById("Product_Name").value,
            qty = document.getElementById("Qty").value,
            rate = document.getElementById("Rate").value,
            amt = document.getElementById("Value").value;

            cell1.innerHTML = code;
            cell2.innerHTML = name;
            cell3.innerHTML = qty;
            cell4.innerHTML = rate;
            cell5.innerHTML = amt;

            var prdtcode = $("#Product_Code").val("");
            var Prdtname = $("#Product_Name").val("");
            var qty = $("#Qty").val("");
            var Rate = $("#Rate").val("");
            var amt = $("#Value").val("");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I am creating a dynamic `HTML` table by using `javascript`,how I save this dynamic html table into database using codeiginter.

Comment: Send an ajax request!

Comment: i am new to ajax,so please tell me in detail

Answer (score 0):

Store whole table html data into one variable

```
var table_data = $("#table_id").html();
$.trim(table_data. replace(/>[\n\t ]+</g, "><"));
```

Now Send this table_data variable to controller function to add data
Make sure the datatype of your field should be text or longtext then normally do the insertdata query in controller's function.

The ajax code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
url:"path to your controller function",
type: 'POST',
data:{
    table_data:table_data,
},
success:function(result){
   console.log(result);
},
});
```

The controller's function code is as below:

```
function insert_table_data(){
    $data = array('table_data' => $this->input->post('table_data'));
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

Comment: In controller,how to i use this table variable name.

Comment: Through ajax you can send this variable to controller function. and then you can insert it to database

Comment: i knew,in controller function how i use this variable to save into database.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Here I update the code with ajax request and the controller's function

Comment: Have you check the data inside $this->input->post('table_data')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181876/discussion-between-pragna-and-esakkichandra).